# Chef LWRP recipe Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am using the chef community java cookbook to install java on CentOS 7.2. I have an LWRP recipe that is not working

I build up my install parameters via the java_ark section

```
op_sys = node['os']

# Used to get the required java update from the environment file
java_ver_update = node['java_ver']

# Logic for each OS
if op_sys == 'linux'

# Java_ark, which is used to define the correct install attributes for each OS type (win/linux)
  install_dir = node['install_dir']
  java_ark "jdk" do
    url 'http://sv-dc01.sv.local/install_artifacts/java/oracle/JRE/jre-'+"#{java_ver_update}"+'-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    app_home install_dir
    owner 'root'
    group 'wheel'
    app_home_mode 774
    action :install
  end

  # Set the folder permissions
  execute "chown-dir" do
    command "chmod -R 774 #{install_dir}"
    action :run
  end
end
```

Here is my environment file where I have set some node attributes to be called in the main recipe

```
name 'env_workstation_dubbo'
description "Environment Workstation Dubbo"
cookbook_versions({
    "ohai" => "> 0.0.1",
    "java" => "> 0.1.0",
    "install_java" => "> 0.0.1"
})

$environment = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
$override = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

$override['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
$override['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
$override['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
$override['java']['set_default'] = false
# Custom attributes/variables to be placed here
$override['java_ver'] = '8u77'
$override['install_dir'] = '/applications/'


default_attributes(Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.merge($_default_environment, $environment))
override_attributes($override)
```

And here is what happens during the `sudo chef-client` run on the CentOS machine I am using for testing:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.16.42
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["install_java"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - install_java (0.2.0)
  - java (1.43.0)
  - compat_resource (12.16.2)
  - ohai (4.2.2)
  - seven_zip (2.0.2)
  - homebrew (2.1.2)
  - apt (5.0.0)
  - build-essential (7.0.2)
  - windows (2.1.1)
  - mingw (1.2.4)
  - ark (2.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2016-12-12T11:04:24+13:00] WARN: Chef::Provider::AptRepository already exists!  Cannot create deprecation class for LWRP provider apt_repository from cookbook apt
[2016-12-12T11:04:24+13:00] WARN: AptRepository already exists!  Deprecation class overwrites Custom resource apt_repository from cookbook apt
Converging 8 resources
Recipe: install_java::default
  * java_ark[jdk] action install

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'java_ark[jdk]'
    ================================================================================

    Errno::ENOENT
    -------------
    No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - 

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/providers/ark.rb:115:in `block in class_from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/install_java/recipes/default.rb

     18:   java_ark "jdk" do
     19:     url 'http://sv-dc01.sv.local/install_artifacts/java/oracle/JRE/jre-'+"#{java_ver_update}"+'-linux-x64.tar.gz'
     20:     app_home install_dir
     21:     owner 'root'
     22:     group 'wheel'
     23:     app_home_mode 774
     24:     action :install
     25:   end
     26: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/install_java/recipes/default.rb:18:in `from_file'

    java_ark("jdk") do
      action [:install]
      supports {:report=>true, :exception=>true}
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :java_ark
      cookbook_name "install_java"
      recipe_name "default"
      url "http://sv-dc01.sv.local/install_artifacts/java/oracle/JRE/jre-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz"
      app_home "/applications/"
      owner "root"
      group "wheel"
      app_home_mode 774
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 17 seconds
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] ERROR: java_ark[jdk] (install_java::default line 18) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - 
[2016-12-12T11:04:25+13:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it can't find the file or directory or get a completed install of Java working???

Comment: Did you upload your environment to the chef server ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your environment is not applied correctly. I mean, if you machine is not using your `'env_workstation_dubbo'` environment, the `node['install_dir']` attribute will not be correctly set. You can read how to set the environment for a node [here](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#set-for-a-node).

Another possibility is that you are using a modified version of the `java` cookbook that uses `mkdir` instead of `mkdir_p`. I say that because I have not been able to find your `2.0.0` java cookbook version in the supermarket. Where are you getting that cookbook from?

### Update after downgraded to `java` cookbook version `v1.43.0`

The problem is that the `install_dir` must be at least 2 directory level deep, following the `app_root/app_name` format. For example `"/applications/default"`.

If you use `"/applications"` as `install_dir`, `app_name` will be `"applications"`, `app_root` will be empty and the latter will cause the mkdir error when trying to create the *application root* directory.

Comment: I was mucking around with the Java cookbook (which was failing before and after I mucked around) I have reverted to version is 1.43.0, but the error persists.
The environment file is being loaded - Otherwise my URL for the tarball path would give me an HTTP 404 error as I pull the update number from here to build/complete the URL for the installer.

Comment: Could you update the log output in your question based on the java cookbook version `1.43.0` you are now using? Even if the error is the same, seeing the exact source lines that are failing would help in debugging the error.

Comment: Updated as requested.